# Tell browser to always display MathJax as SVG?

Tags: browser, mathjax

Lots of sites (or at least the ones I look at) have MathJax math support.  However, the default in just about every one seems to be to display as HTML/CSS, which simply does not work on any browser I've tried.  Doing a right-click on an equation and selecting 'display as SVG' gives me the equations, but it's a pain having to do it for every site.  Is there a way to tell the browser (via a user.css file or similar) to always display as SVG?

The MathJax site implies that it should be possible through web site config files, but all the documentation is addressed to people who are building web sites.  I'm just viewing other people's sites.

Comment: MathJax stores the renderer setting in a browser cookie, and cookies are site-specific.  I do not know a way to handle global preferences in a secure way.  Once you have set your preference for a site, it should remain in effect for a year (unless you block cookies), so at least for the the sites you visit frequently, you should not have to set it again.

Comment: Can you way what is not working with the HTML-CSS output for you?  And can you indicate your operating system (and version) and the browsers (and versions) that you have tried?